# ROP - ret VS ret 0

Tags: assembly, binary-code, rop

I'm doing a binary challenge from pwnable.kr and I'm examining a some ROP gadget.

Until now I've always used gadget ending with `ret` or `syscall/int 0x80`, but now ROPgadget gave me a gadget ending with `ret 0`.

What's the difference wrt `ret`?

Comment: You can set an offset on ret like `ret 4` so i assume that `ret` Is the same of `ret 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not strictly a security question but the short answer is that there is no functional difference between `ret` and `ret 0`. In-fact, this notation is often compiler independent for some bizarre reason.

The reason for your notation is being displayed as `ret 0` is likely due to a `ret imm16=0` instruction. MSVC for example emits `ret` as `ret 0`. However, these are exactly the same instruction in terms of operation. If you want to visualise the difference, compile a simple:

```
xor eax, eax 
ret 0
```

in MASM and then compile the same program in NASM. NASM will likely optimize the above to

```
xor eax, eax
ret
```

whereas MASM will display it as the former with the `ret 0`.